# regular expression to not match something in quotes

Tags: regex, preg-match, regex-negation

I have this bit of regex used in a php preg_match to strip out trailing spaces from ":" and "("

```
([\(:])\s+
```

The problem I'm running into is that it ends up stripping out spaces I need that are within quotes.  For example, this string:

```
img[style*="float: left"]
```

Is there a way to write the regex so it will match any ":" or "(" unless it is enclosed in double quotes?

Comment: If you're just looking for trailing space, can't you just add an end of line (`$`) to your regex so that it doesn't match colons and parentheses inside of strings?

Comment: I want the space stripped out from within string, not just those at the end of a line.  I just want stuff enclosed in quotes to be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

This routine will:

- skip the matches found inside the quotes
- replace matches found outside the quotes

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/VEzSLK)

**Code**

```
<?php

$string = 'img[style*="float: left"]
img: [style*="float: left"]
img( [style*="float: left"]
';


    $regex = '/"[^"]*"|([:(])\s+/ims';

    $output = preg_replace_callback(
        $regex,
        function ($matches) {
            if (array_key_exists (1, $matches)) {
                return $matches[1] ;
            }
            return $matches[0];
        },
        $string
    );
    echo "this is the output:"  . $output;
```

**Output**

```
this is the output:img[style*="float: left"]
img:[style*="float: left"]
img([style*="float: left"]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about this:

1. You can use negative lookarounds (information [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) to try and assert that there is not a double quote before or after something you don't want stripped. The problem I have with this is that there is no indication of how far away from the quotes `:` or `(` might be, and lookarounds cannot be of unknown length.
2. What I like to do, is to "preserve" anything enclosed within double quotes, with the regex `\"[^"]+\"` within an array, and replacing them with a string (I use "THIS_IS_A_QUOTE"). After you have stored all your quotes in an array, strip all spaces, and finally restore all "THIS_IS_A_QUOTE" strings with the strings in the array.

Comment: That's a clever way to do it.  If I can't get one of the other solutions to work I'll give #2 a try.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$text = preg_replace('~(?|(\\\{2}|\\\"|"(?>[^"\\\]+|\\\{2}|\\\")*+")|([:(])\s+)~', '$1', $text);
```

The idea is to match double quotes parts before `([:(])\s+` and replace them by themselves.

To avoid to match escaped quotes, backslashes are matched before.

pattern details:

```
~                                    # pattern delimiter
(?|                                  # branch reset : all capture groups inside have the same number
    (                                # open a capturing group
        \\\{2}                       # group of 2 backslashes (can't escape everything)
      |                              # OR
        \\\"                         # an escaped double quote
      |                              # OR
        "(?>[^"\\\]+|\\\{2}|\\\")*+" # content inside double quotes
    )                                # close the capturing group
  |                                  # OR
    ( [:(] )                         # a : or a ( in a capturing group
    \s+                              # spaces
)                                    # close the branch reset group
~                                    # pattern delimiter
```

The interest is to deal with this kind of situations:

```
img: " : \" ( "
img: \" : ( " ( "
img: \\" : ( " ( "
```

result:

```
img:" : \" ( "
img:\" :(" ( "
img:\\" : ( " ("
```